# How solve c++ POCO lib linking error on ARM Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, poco, arm-linux

I try to link the Poco C++ library with my project on ARM Linux, but I get the linking error.
Link error message:

```
foo.so: undefined reference to `Poco::JSON::Object::Object(int)'
foo.so: undefined reference to `Poco::JSON::Array::Array(int)'
foo.so: undefined reference to `Poco::JSON::Parser::Parser(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::JSON::Handler, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::JSON::Handler> > const&)'
foo.so: undefined reference to `Poco::format(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char const*, std::vector<Poco::Any, std::allocator<Poco::Any> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Poco was built with `crossbuild-essential-armhf` tools and used this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-get update
apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf -y

git clone -b poco-1.11.1-release https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
cd poco
./configure --config=ARM-Linux --everything --no-tests --no-samples --omit=PDF,Crypto,NetSSL_OpenSSL,JWT,Data/MySQL,Data/ODBC,Data/PostgreSQL &&
          make all -s -j4 ARCHFLAGS="-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon" TOOL=arm-linux-gnueabihf && make install
cd ../
```

But the project was built with `g++` compiler.

Also here is the projects `CMakeLists.txt` file. The 20th version of CMake has been used

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)

project("test")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation Net Util)

add_definitions(-std=c++1z -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_AUTO_PTR)
SET(SRC_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)
file(GLOB SRCS_PATH ${SRC_PATH}*.cpp)

SET(EXECS ${SRC_PATH}/main.cpp)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS_PATH})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Poco::Net Poco::Util Poco::Foundation)

FOREACH(exec_src ${EXECS})
    get_filename_component(exec_name ${exec_src} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${exec_name} ${exec_src})
    target_link_libraries(${exec_name} ${PROJECT_NAME})
ENDFOREACH()
```